# Nodemailer in vercel not sending email in production

Tags: next.js, sendgrid, nodemailer, vercel

I'm using Nodemailer to send emails in my serverless Next.js project, deployed in Vercel, which works perfectly in development mode. But I'm having problems in production. No error returned, everything works the same way as is development mode, except I don't receive any email.

I have another project built with React and deployed in Heroku where I send emails the same way and it works fine, development and production, so I understand the problem is with Vercel.

Yes, I enabled "Allow Less Secured Apps" in Google account and yes, I enabled Captcha.

I also read this https://vercel.com/docs/solutions/email but it doesn't really make me understand what I should do in my case. I can see it's a matter of SMTP but I don't know what exactly.

Anybody experienced this kind of problem? How can I fix this?

```
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "smtp.gmail.com",
    port: 465,
    auth: {
        user: myEmail@gmail.com,
        pass: myEmailPass
    }
});
            
const mailOptions = {
    from: `${req.body.name} ${req.body.email}`,
    to: myEmail@gmail.com,
    subject: `${req.body.subject}`,
    text: `Text: ${req.body.text}`
}
            
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (err, res) => {
    if(err) {
          console.log(err);
    } else {
          console.log("success");
    }
});
```

**UPDATE**

I changed to SendGrid: made an account, created an API Key, and changed the code like so(instead the one above):

```
sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);
const msg = {
    to: `myEmail@gmail.com`,
    from: `myEmail@gmail.com`,
    subject: `${req.body.subject}`,
    text: `${req.body.text}`
};
sgMail
.send(msg)
.then(() => {
     console.log('email sent')
})
.catch((error) => {
     console.error("error", error)
});
```

It logs out "email sent" but I don't receive any email.
It's the same problem like with Nodemailer.
I'm confused now...

Comment: did you find the solution?? i am experiencing the same issue, its frustrating when every thing works fine in development but creates problem in production

Comment: I ended up using sendgrid. Try making the parent function async and add await to sendgrid, like so: await sgMail.send(msg) ...... Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: yes i did the same,shifted to sendgrid from nodemailer,its working fine,instead of async await i used then and catch with the sendgrid as per their doucumentation

Comment: there is 2 issues here... first you need to use async/await in your functions and then you need to remove the nodemailer callback.... because otherwise it does not return a promise so it does not wait for the execution... the script in vercel is being terminated before the email is sent thats why you do not receive it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have already encountered the same problem, nodemailer was not working on vercel but on heroku everything worked perfectly. it is specified in the doc that vercel does not block stmp connections but according to what I have experienced, in practice stmp connections are blocked. what you can do is use an alternative to nodemailer. use sendgrid and it works fine

[An article on how integrating Sendgrid with Next.js](https://dev.to/markdrew53/integrating-sendgrid-with-next-js-4f5m)

Comment: So I followed your advice, I made an account on SendGrid, created an APIKey and instead of my code above, I wrote this: https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/tree/main/packages/mail#quick-start-hello-email . Same thing, no errors, everything works fine, but no mail received. Even in SendGrid dashboard I cannot find any activity. Do you have any idea what's happening? I'm updating my initial post so you can understand better...

Comment: Can you console log that response on api and see what's happening?

Comment: @DanielIoanitescu I suggest you check the IP Access Management section from your SendGrid dashboard, SendGrid must be blocking IP's of your production deployments and thus it might be failing to send Emails, you need to allow all IP's to send Emails from SendGrid Dashboard for vercel's deployment to work as expected because vercel deployment's don't have static IP it can change at any time as your app scales.

Answer (score 46):

I ran into this issue and managed to fix it and keep using nodemailer by adding in promises with async/await.

```
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

export default async (req, res) => {

const { firstName, lastName, email, message } = JSON.parse(req.body);

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    port: 465,
    host: "smtp.gmail.com",
    auth: {
        user: "myEmail@gmail.com",
        pass: "password",
    },
    secure: true,
});

await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // verify connection configuration
    transporter.verify(function (error, success) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
            reject(error);
        } else {
            console.log("Server is ready to take our messages");
            resolve(success);
        }
    });
});

const mailData = {
    from: {
        name: `${firstName} ${lastName}`,
        address: "myEmail@gmail.com",
    },
    replyTo: email,
    to: "recipient@gmail.com",
    subject: `form message`,
    text: message,
    html: `${message}`,
};

await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // send mail
    transporter.sendMail(mailData, (err, info) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            reject(err);
        } else {
            console.log(info);
            resolve(info);
        }
    });
});

res.status(200).json({ status: "OK" });
};
```

Comment: this also works to me!

Comment: this should be the correct answer! this worked for me... the issue was that the response was returning earlier than the actual action... I do not know why await does not work on the server event

Comment: To add to this now you have to enable 2 step authentication and create password and put in that password

Comment: this works in vercel but on my vps it fails :(

Answer (score 7):

This problem is really confusing indeed. I've managed to fix this by simply adding async/await. This is because streaming responses (fire-and-forget functions) are not supported by Vercel.

Source: https://vercel.com/docs/platform/limits#streaming-responses

Comment: Yes, I also added async/await a while ago, for the sendGrid example. The problem is that sendGrid sends emails in Spam folder. Nodemailer sends to Inbox but doesn't work together with Vercel. Don't know what to do and what to choose now, probably I'll try other services until I find something that works properly.

Answer (score 5):

in case someone bump on this in the future:

for nuxt3 in vercel (is not next but it should apply too)

```
export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  await mailTransport.sendMail(mailOptions);

  return {}
}
```

You need to remove the callback from the nodemailer sendEmail function otherwise it does not return a promise... this cause the script in vercel to be terminated earlier hence not email being sent!

> If callback argument is not set then the method returns a Promise
> object. Nodemailer itself does not use Promises internally but it
> wraps the return into a Promise for convenience.

also applicable to nodejs

Comment: Removing the callback worked! thanks.

Comment: I am running into this issue with Nuxt 3, Vercel and Nuxt-Auth too! Where did you add this above code to fix the issue?

Comment: @jnarowski well it depends where you are calling you sendEmail method... just make sure you are using an async function and use the sendEmail method on the same way as I did

Comment: This fixed it for me using Next app router 2024

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue with Nodemailer but I fixed it by first adding the environment variables in Vercel then commit to the github(It will automatically be uploaded on vercel). So add the variables to vercel first for it to take effect

Comment: This is the solution that worked for me, glad you shared it.
Adding the env variables in Varcel dashboard instead of using (.env) will allow the API to get the values because they're hidden from the API since it's not pushed to git that's why Varcel can't access those variables.

Answer (score 2):

In my own case, wrapping my email function with async solved it for me.

eg:

```
const sendMessage = async(message)=>{
  await transporter.sendMail({...options here})
}
```

Then in my API I called my function using:

```
await sendMessage('your message')
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the `async/await` responses and didn't work at the beginning. Digging through the real time `functions` logs of the app, I noticed that there was an `Error: Missing credentials for "PLAIN"`, so all I had to do was add the respective `.env` variables to vercel environment variables and it worked. Here's the complete code though:

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'

type Data = any
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer')

const auth = {
  user: process.env.WEB_MAILER,
  pass: process.env.WEB_MAILER_PASSWORD,
}

export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse<Data>
) {
  const { name, email, subject, message } = req.body

  const mailData = {
    to: process.env.EMAIL_TO,
    from: process.env.WEB_MAILER,
    name: name,
    subject: subject,
    text: `Email: ${email}.\n\nMessage: ${message}`,
    html: `<div>Email: ${email}.\n\nMessage: ${message}</div>`,
  }

  const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp.titan.email',
    secure: true,
    port: 465,
    auth: auth,
  })

  const server = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // verify connection configuration
    transporter.verify(function (error: any, success: any) {
      if (success) {
        resolve(success)
      }
      reject(error)
    })
  })
  if (!server) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error failed' })
  }

  const success = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // send mail
    transporter.sendMail(mailData).then((info: any, err: any) => {
      if (info.response.includes('250')) {
        resolve(true)
      }
      reject(err)
    })
  })

  if (!success) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error sending email' })
  }
  res.status(200).json({ success: success })
}
```

Comment: try my answer, it should work

Answer (score 0):

i encounter this same problem in nodemailer and nextjs14, and its very frustrating but i think i will not use nodemailer with nextjs14 as it have been on nextjs documentation that they block SMTP connection, here is the link as reference.

https://vercel.com/guides/sending-emails-from-an-application-on-vercel

Comment: I encountered this issue with NextJS 14 as well. The solution was what @Tomas suggested,  I simply made the wrapper function asynchronous and removed the callback in the sendMail method