# Emails aren't sending in production, using nodemailer, gmail (gcloud host if that matters). Localhost is fine however

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, gmail, nodemailer

I have tried a lot of solutions that worked for others on here, but I've been tackling this for a few days and am still at a loss. For some reason, sending emails via localhost works perfectly, but when the site is live, it does not. Here is my code:

```
app.post('/contact', (req, res) => {

const CLIENT_ID = process.env.C_ID;
const CLIENT_SECRET = process.env.C_SECRET;
const REDIRECT_URI = 'https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground';
const REFRESH_TOKEN = process.env.R_TOKEN;

const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, REDIRECT_URI);

oAuth2Client.setCredentials({ refresh_token: REFRESH_TOKEN });

async function sendMail() {

    try {
        const accessToken = await oAuth2Client.getAccessToken();

        const transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
            service: 'gmail',
            auth: {
                type: 'OAuth2',
                user: process.env.EMAIL_USER,
                clientId: CLIENT_ID,
                clientSecret: CLIENT_SECRET,
                refreshToken: REFRESH_TOKEN,
                accessToken: accessToken,
            },
        });

        const mailOptions = {
            from: req.body.email,
            to: process.env.EMAIL_USER,
            subject: `Message from ${req.body.email}`,
            text: req.body.message
        };

        const result = await transport.sendMail(mailOptions)
        return result

    } catch (error) {
        return error
    }
}

sendMail()
    .then((result) => console.log('Email sent: ', result), res.send('success'))
    .catch((error) => console.log(error.message));
```

});

Here are the main solutions I've tried:

- https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps
- https://accounts.google.com/b/0/displayunlockcaptcha
- Previously added "port: 465" and "host: "smtp.gmail.com"" lines above auth as well but that was a no-go.
- If it's any help, here is the tutorial video I followed for the nodemailer settings: https://youtu.be/-rcRf7yswfM

Any ideas? Thank you for reading.

EDIT: To add to this, I'm not getting any error messages no matter what I do. To preface this, I'm relatively new at this.

EDIT*: I tried to send an email via the web server on google cloud SDK(?) and this came up:

Error: No refresh token is set. Which doesn't make too much sense to me.

Also saw this in there which I didn't understand:

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution that works for me : you have to add promises with async/await. In my case, I moved to Sendgrid, I had the same bug and I resolve it with this snippet:

```
import nodemailer from "nodemailer";

export default async (req, res) => {
    require('dotenv').config()
    const nodemailer = require('nodemailer')

    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      host: 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
      port: 587,
      auth: {
        user: process.env.SENDGRID_USERNAME,
        pass: process.env.SENDGRID_PASSWORD,
      },
    })

    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // verify connection configuration
        transporter.verify(function (error, success) {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
                reject(error);
            } else {
                console.log("Server is ready to take our messages");
                resolve(success);
            }
        });
    });

    const mailData = {
      from: process.env.SENDGRID_SENDER,
      to:  "xxxxx@gmail.com",
      subject: `Message du site par ${req.body.name}`,
      text: req.body.message + " | Envoyé par: " + req.body.email + " | Numéro de tel: " + req.body.tel,
      html: `<div>${req.body.message}</div>
      <p>Envoyé par:${req.body.email}</p>
      <p>Numéro de tel:${req.body.tel}</p>`
    }
    
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // send mail
        transporter.sendMail(mailData, (err, info) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                reject(err);
            } else {
                console.log(info);
                resolve(info);
            }
        });
    });

    return res.status(200).json({ status: "OK" });
  }
```

[The original answer is here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65631481/nodemailer-in-vercel-not-sending-email-in-production)

Answer (score 0):

in the nodemailer website you have this:
"Even though Gmail is the fastest way to get started with sending emails, it is by no means a preferable solution unless you are using OAuth2 authentication. Gmail expects the user to be an actual user not a robot so it runs a lot of heuristics for every login attempt and blocks anything that looks suspicious to defend the user from account hijacking attempts. **For example you might run into trouble if your server is in another geographical location – everything works in your dev machine but messages are blocked in production.**"

More on using gmail with nodemailer here: https://nodemailer.com/usage/using-gmail/