# Why is my Astro api route working locally, but no on Vercel?

Tags: typescript, deployment, server-side-rendering, vercel, astrojs

I've set up an api route that uses nodemailer to send an email. Calling the POST request locally in dev mode works perfectly but upon running it via vercel hosting it times out my serverless function.

Here's the code for calling the api, which is inside a .tsx component:

```
const sendEmail = async (email: string) => {
      await fetch('/api/sendmail.json', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({ email }),
        })
        .then((res) => {
          if (!res.ok) {
            throw new Error()
          }
          return res.json()
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log('Error', err)
          throw new Error('Network error.')
        })
    }
```

And here's my astro.config.mjs:

```
import vercel from "@astrojs/vercel/serverless";

export default defineConfig({
  integrations: [tailwind(), react()],
  output: 'hybrid',
  adapter: vercel()
});
```

I've tried changing the output mode to 'server' and changing the page's prerender. But it just made the page not load.

Im pretty new to astro so i'd really appreciate the help, thanks!

Gonza

Comment: Check your Vercel logs to see if there's errors being logged serverside (in your API route). You may need to add more logging if you don't see anything useful. If the Vercel function is timing out, then the API route is likely failing silently somewhere (e.g. it's not returning a response and also not throwing an error).

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Alex! Checking the logs I found this error: `2023-11-27T20:05:14.811Z undefined ERROR Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module '/var/task/dist/entry.mjs' imported from /var/task/___vc/__launcher/__launcher.js at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:405:5) at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:332:11) ... `. I get the feeling that the function isn't being hosted correctly...

Comment: I haven't used Astro + Vercel but https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/integrations-guide/vercel/ seems to suggest you need to use `output: 'server'` and not hybrid? Which page (and if you could show a bit of its code) didn't work when you tried server/prerender for it? You only need to use prerender (true) if that page should be static.

Comment: From what I gathered from the docs, hybrid should work as long as I add `export const prerender = false;` to the page I need to run the function. When I switch over to `output: 'server'` none of my pages load unless I specify `prerender = true` which just leads us back to the same issue. Here's some of the code from my index.astro file which contains a .tsx file which I need to call the function, its a pretty simple astro page. `--- 
import ...
---
<Layout title="Boulder Tech">
 <main>
  ...
 </main>
</Layout>`

Comment: @Alex Sorry not quite sure how to format it properly, new to stackoverflow.

Comment: Have you figgured it out? I have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that it shouldn't be a problem with your implementation but with using Nodemailer in Vercel.
See this question & answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65634795/12224431